# Is it appropriate to set Activity into a view model class?

Tags: android

According to MVVM structure, i use view model to handle button click event to change Activity like below

```
public class ParentViewModel {

// Target Activity
protected Activity activity;

/* ------------------------------ Destroy */

/**
 * Release memory when destroy
 */
public void destroy() {
    activity = null;
}

/* ------------------------------ Button Event */

public void onClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, B_Activity.class);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

Although i will call destroy method in ParentViewModel when Activity onDestroy triggered, but i still not sure it is appropriate or not (like may due to memory leak ... etc), does anyone can give suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

What about garbage collector? Idisposable interface?